# C++ Passing variable to a function changes what is read from the variable

Tags: c++

```
static void traverse_nodes ( vector<Node*> sg ) {
  cout << "Type: " << sg[0].get_type() << "\n";
}

int main () {
  vector<Node*> scene_graph;
  scene_graph = {...};

  cout << "Type: " << scene_graph[0].get_type() << "\n";
  traverse_nodes(scene_graph);
}
```

returns:

```
Type: type_first
Type: unknown_type
```

In my actual code I call get_type() on the scene_graph and then immediately jump into traverse_nodes() and call it again on the local version of the scene_graph like I wrote here.

Answer (score 0):

Realized the answer as I was typing the question.

I had to pass the vector by reference like so:

```
static void traverse_nodes (vector<Node*>&) {
```

I believe it's because otherwise the compiler tries to copy the vector but it doesn't know how because node is a custom struct/class and I haven't defined the assignment operator for it.

Comment: Your vector is a vector of pointers. Copying it copies the pointer. Your explanation makes no sense. There is probably a mistake elsewhere in your code that still needs fixing, e.g. perhaps your vectors contains dangling pointers pointing into the stack.